# MG2 Integration give error Unable to post data to consumer due to an unexpected error

Tags: magento2, api, setup-script, integration

I'm follow the http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/integration.html and i have an error when i try do activates the integrator.

```
[2017-06-20 05:22:08] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Notice: Undefined index: TestIntegration in /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-integration/Model/Plugin/Integration.php on line 121 in /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-integration/Model/Plugin/Integration.php(121): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/srv/www/vendor...', 121, Array)
#1 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-integration/Model/Plugin/Integration.php(101): Magento\Integration\Model\Plugin\Integration->_addAllowedResources(Object(Magento\Integration\Model\Integration))
#2 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(152): Magento\Integration\Model\Plugin\Integration->afterGet(Object(Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Integration\Model\Integration))
#3 /srv/www/var/generation/Magento/Integration/Model/IntegrationService/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array)
#4 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/PermissionsDialog.php(23): Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService\Interceptor->get(2)
#5 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog->execute()
#6 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#9 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Integra...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#10 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Integra...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#13 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /srv/www/var/generation/Magento/Integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/PermissionsDialog/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#16 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\PermissionsDialog\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#20 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /srv/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#23 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#25 /srv/www/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#26 {main} [] []
```

**My files:**

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
   /**
   * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
   -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sc_IntegrationAPI" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Integration"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> etc/integrations/api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <integrations>
        <integration name="testIntegration">
            <resources>
                <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Log::online, its parent Magento_Customer::customer needs to be declared as well-->
                <resource name="Magento_Customer::customer"/>
                <resource name="Magento_Log::online"/>
                <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Sales::reorder, all its parent resources need to be declared-->
                <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales"/>
                <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation"/>
                <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order"/>
                <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions"/>
                <resource name="Magento_Sales::reorder"/>
            </resources>
        </integration>
    </integrations>
</config>
```

> etc/integrations/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<integrations>
    <integration name="TestIntegration">
        <email>nolopetize@gmail.com</email>
        <endpoint_url>http://default.sc.local/oauth.php</endpoint_url>
        <identity_link_url>http://default.sc.local/oauth.php</identity_link_url>
    </integration>
</integrations>
```

> etc/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
 namespace Sc\IntegrationAPI\Setup;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 use Magento\Integration\Model\ConfigBasedIntegrationManager;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
     /**
      * @var ConfigBasedIntegrationManager
      */


     private $integrationManager;

     /**
      * @param ConfigBasedIntegrationManager $integrationManager
      */

     public function __construct(ConfigBasedIntegrationManager $integrationManager)
     {
         $this->integrationManager = $integrationManager;
     }

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */

     public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
         $this->integrationManager->processIntegrationConfig(['testIntegration']);
     }
 }
```

> Module/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "Sc_IntegrationAPI",
  "description": "create integration from config",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "2.0.0",
    "magento/module-integration": "2.0.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Sc\\IntegrationAPI\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

> Module/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sc_IntegrationAPI',
    __DIR__
);
```

**EDIT:** I followed answers below, and i have another error:

```
Unable to post data to consumer due to an unexpected error
```

What is it? thanks

Comment: When you get error `Unable to post data to consumer due to an unexpected error` the exception is not printed by default. Please, check your `exception.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check our xml files. In your config.xml file, integration name is "TestIntegration" and in api.xml file, integration name is "iestIntegration" . Please firstly resolve this. If you are still facing issue. Please let me know.

Comment: yes, still the same error.

Comment: Please delete all static files and flush the cache.

Comment: I did this and it continues with the same error when I try to activate the Integrator in ""System > Integrations""

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my dev-server and found the issue: the path `etc/integrations/` should be `etc/integration/` (without **`s`** at the end). At this point first error is gone, but another one is thrown:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>   Invalid Document
>   Element 'config': No matching global declaration available for the
>   validation root.     Line: 2

The problem is in the `etc/integration/api.xml` config. It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<integrations>
    <integration name="TestIntegration">
        <resources>
            <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Log::online, its parent Magento_Customer::customer needs to be declared as well-->
            <resource name="Magento_Customer::customer"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Log::online"/>
            <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Sales::reorder, all its parent resources need to be declared-->
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions"/>
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::reorder"/>
        </resources>
    </integration>
</integrations>
```

Without `<config>` node, as it declared in the `.xsd` file:

> magento/module-integration/etc/integration/api.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Schema for API integration configuration.
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 @deprecated
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="integrations" type="integrationsType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="integrationsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="integration" type="integrationType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="integrationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="resources" type="resourcesType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="integrationNameType" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="resourcesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="resource" type="resourceType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="resourceType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="resourceNameType" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="resourceNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value=".+_.+::.+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="integrationNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I tried with these changes, but I still can not activate the integrator and the error remains the same as exception.log. I will try on a new installation of magento2.

Comment: @MatheusSilvaItep Try to remove the integration and reinstall the module

Comment: ok, i almost can activate now. Give me another error: Unable to post data to consumer due to an unexpected error

Comment: @MatheusSilvaItep update your question with corresponding error from log.